# How to batch open URLs in QuickTime and batch save videos to the disk?

Tags: automation, quicktime, batch-processing

I have hundreds of URLs to QT movies that I need to save on my local computer.
Right now my workflow is as such: click on list of URL, copy next URL, click on QT, press cmd U, paste the URL, press Enter, wait for it to load, press cmd S, name the file (I know each's title) and press Enter, repeat.
As you can see it's a particularly tedious task and I would really like to speed up the process.

I'll take any solution you offer me, Automator action, AppleScript, Terminal command, JAVA  but it has to run on OS X 10.6

Ideally I’d like each movie to be saved with a unique name that I’ll have to specify next to the URL, before batching (some XML list I imagine).
Customising the URLs and title should be simple for me. I’ll do several  batches of 100 or so URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If those are really URLs to the videos (not some kind of "playlist"), then you don't need any specialized tools at all, just a downloader. I see that Automator has a "Download URLs" action; perhaps that will do.

I get the impression you might want to rename the files something other than their URLs; if so, could you edit your question to explain in what format you have the URLs and titles?

Comment: URLs look like this `http://domain.com:80/movplayer/getplayer.php?f=/dir1/movies/04/0408.mov` but when access from a browser the port is removed access is restricted. Downloaders say the file doesn’t exist. However from QT it's fine.